# if statement, need 3 results

Tags: excel, formula

Asked this question earlier, hopefully I can craft it better.
I have 5 columns each, that could have dates entered. If the date is less than 14 days, the status column shows "current" if false it shows "overdue". But I need to add: if any date is entered into the 5th column the status column will show "complete"

Comment: Formulas or vba? Couldn't you just check to see if the cell was blank or not? =IF("E1"<>"","Complete","")

Comment: that's definitely not clear...

Comment: I would suggest posting some mock  up sample data and expected results.

Comment: It would look something like this: `=IF(E1<>"","Complete",IF(INDEX(A1:D1,1,COUNTA(A1:D1))>=(TODAY()-14),"Overdue","Current"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now this is what I'm envisioning...
[image]

but what you're after and your current setup is very unclear...

Comment: Yes, this is a duplicate of "tracking status" I thought maybe this was more clear. I couldn't get the other formula to work.

Comment: XqBERT: That's it! I know it is probably straightforward and simple, but I have been working it and just couldn't get it.  Thanks for your help on an unclear question/problem!